# AUC-ROC interpretation

Tags: statistical-significance, roc, auc

I performed AUC-ROC curve analysis to confirm the biomarker potential of genes that were significant in gene expression results. This is how the graphics came out in the genes I determined. How can I comment, can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Please provide details about your analysis: what's the data and how did you analyze it. I would check for errors in the implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

An AUC of 1 means your model perfectly classifies the outcome 100 percent of the time. I would be a bit wary depending on what this data is like, as this may be a sign of overfitting or misspecification.

Comment: What would you recommend in this situation?
I have a control and experimental group, and the study was repeated 3 times.

Comment: Have you looked at the outcomes of your data in any other way? May be helpful to plot or inspect your data to see what is afoot. Otherwise I can't really say.

Comment: My data is:
GRUPLAR Chst2
KONTROL 3,582099
DENEY         24,23418

Comment: Since I have 2 groups, I did the T test. I confirmed the genes with significant t-test results with ROC curve analysis.

Comment: You need to look at the data distributions, regression assumptions, etc. and see if there is something weird going on. I'm not sure what t-test you did but either way you need to look further.

Comment: As a result of statistical analysis, data distributions were homogeneous.